# How to call so SIP from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sip

I've tried about 20 libraries, but none of them can do the basic thing "make a call".

Hi my SIP operator does not support WebSockets and WebRTC. And all the data that have given me this:

username: +790434344334
pass: dsfsfdsff
domain: sbc.megafon.ru
two ports: 5060, 8080
Transport: UDP, TCP

is there any nodejs library in the world that is capable of doing this simple thing:

nodejs index.js:

```js
import SipClient from 'super-node-sip-library-without-websockers'

const client = new SipClient({
  domain: "sbc.megafon.ru",
  username: "+790434344334",
  pass: "dsfsfdsff"
})

const callSession = client.call("911")

callSession.inputAudioStream // audio stream
callSession.outputAudioStream // audio stream

// play sound
const localMp3FileStream = require('./localAudioFileStream.js')
localMp3FileStream.pipe(callSession.outputAudioStream) // connect local audio file to output stream
    
// send sms
callSession.sms("Sms text")
```

In other words, i just need to receive a nodeReadableStream from the SIP network with the sound of the voice that the person speaks to the phone, as well as send a nodeWritableStream to the SIP network with the sounds that I want

Is it really impossible to make SIP calls with node js?

Comment: Found solution?

Answer (score 0):

> username: +790434344334 pass: dsfsfdsff domain: sbc.megafon.ru two
> ports: 5060, 8080 Transport: UDP, TCP

With this registration information, you can use a sip phone ; among all possibilities you try linphone and make incoming/outgoing basic calls from/to your smartphone or any other.

> is there any nodejs library in the world that is capable of doing this
> simple thing: ... Is it really impossible to make SIP calls with node
> js?

It is not so simple, a full stack SIP with node JS is a big thing, I do not think that it is available.
However a practical approach is to do a kind of *proxying* , you may try to find a proxy sip, on github the first one is

```
https://github.com/drachtio/drachtio-rtpengine-webrtcproxy.
```

Comment: proxying need if i use browser and WebRTC with Websockets, but nodejs is native platform, i think none js can use SIP(TCP/UDP)

Comment: It is not impossible to do that but why doing a new SIP stack in nodejs or even harder a new SIP stack full js? 
If tou really want to do that maybe the safe way is to reuse kamalio (a kind of SIP toolbox) with nodejs for SIP and a RTP proxy.

Comment: Aaa, that is, just run a ready-made binary sip client and connect it via api to node? Wow), good idea.